# Inserir um ID no SQL+PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-insert

Estou fazendo um formulário onde o usuário insere os dados e o mesmo recebe a confirmação junto com um registro ID no php com sql, só não estou conseguindo essa confirmação final junto com o id, alguém pode me ajudar?

sei que no mysql é assim.

```
$exec_sql = mysql_query($select); 

if (!$exec_sql) {
    print mysql_error();
}
else {
    $id = mysql_insert_id();    
    print '<h3>Registro #'.$id.' inserido com sucesso</h3>';
```

mas e no sql?

Comment: O código parece correto, exceto por usar funções obsoletas mas qual é problema?

Comment: Acredito que esse código esteja correto, mas, os subsequente ou anterior pode conter erros, seria interessante postar todo código. (não utilize mysql por ser obsoleto com já citado)

Answer (score 0):

Um exemplo de código para está ação.

```
<?php
//Define as variáveis do banco
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";

// Cria a conexão
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);

//Verifica a conexão
if($conn->connect_error){
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}else{ 
echo "Conexão ok";
}
//Atribui a consulta a uma variável, você está usando select como nome de variável, mas é presumível um INSERT
$select = "INSERT INTO minhaTabela (colunaFoo, colunaBar)
VALUES ('dadoFoo', 'dadoBar')";

//Executa a consulta
$exec_sql = mysqli_query($conn, $select);

if(!$exec_sql){
print mysqli_error($conn);
}
else{
$id = mysqli_insert_id($conn);    
print '<h3>Registro #'.$id.' inserido com sucesso</h3>'; 
}

//Fecha a conexão   
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Espero que ajude.